# Al usar http get en angular me salta el error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, get

Estoy haciendo una página donde necesito saber saldos de una cuenta. Para hacerlo, utilizo un http get para obtenerlos pero me salta el error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'), y no sé cómo arreglarlo. Los saldos los obtengo de una API.

Tengo el servicio hecho, el model con los datos y ya hice la lógica en el componente, no sé si es algo que se debe arreglar desde front o back.

El servicio:
`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Cuenta } from '../models/cuenta';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MovimientosService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  
  obtenerUltimosMovimientos():Observable<any>
{
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:7195/api/obtenerOperaciones')
}

obtenerSaldo():Observable<Cuenta[]>
{
  return this.http.get<Cuenta[]>('http://localhost:7195/api/obtenerSaldos')
}

 
}
```

`
El model:

`

```
export class Cuenta {
    Saldo:number;
    IdCliente:number;
    IdMoneda:number;
    EstaHabilitada:boolean;
    Cvu:number;

    constructor(Saldo:number, IdCliente:number, IdMoneda:number, EstaHabilitada:boolean, Cvu:number){
        this.Saldo=Saldo;
        this.IdCliente=IdCliente;
        this.IdMoneda=IdMoneda;
        this.EstaHabilitada=EstaHabilitada;
        this.Cvu=Cvu;
    }
}
```

`

La lógica del componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cuenta } from 'src/app/models/cuenta';
import { MovimientosService } from 'src/app/services/movimientos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  saldos:any;
  constructor(private saldo: MovimientosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.saldo.obtenerSaldo());

  }
```

(esto no está terminado, solo tengo el console.log para verificar que funcione)

Comment: Hola Mauro, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Nos falta información para saber qué está pasando. Ese error parece producido por intentar acceder a un array que no existe y no has añadido el código donde ocurre el error. El mensaje de error seguramente muestra el nombre del fichero y la línea en el "stack trace"

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar de la siguiente manera:

En tu servicio:

```
public obtenerSaldo(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:7195/api/obtenerSaldos')
    .pipe(
        (map(response => response)),
        catchError(requestError => this.handleError(requestError))
    );
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    return throwError(error);
}
```

En tu lógica del componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cuenta } from 'src/app/models/cuenta';
import { MovimientosService } from 'src/app/services/movimientos.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  saldos:any;
  cuenta: Cuenta[] = [];
  constructor(private saldo: MovimientosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.saldo.obtenerSaldo().subscribe(
       success => {
        // Imprime la respuesta exitosa del servicio
        console.log(success);
        // Guardas los datos de la respues del servicio 
        this.cuenta = success;
      },
      error => {
        // Imprime si existe algun error al invocar al servicio
        console.log(error);
      }
   );
  }
 }
```